# Ionic3 slider flip effect not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Please check code below, I want to flip my slides but this won't getting applied.I am new in Ionic and trying hard to get it resolve but no effects getting applied.

```
<ion-slides pager #mainslider [effect]=flip>
    <ion-slide>
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <button type="submit"  ion-button color="primary" class="btnNext" (click)="next()">Next holiday</button>
    <button type="submit"  ion-button color="primary" class="btnNext" (click)="prev()">Next holiday</button>
  </ion-slides>



next() {
    this.slides.slideNext();
  }
 prev() {
    this.slides.slidePrev();
  }
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.slides.onlyExternal = true; 
     this.slides.effect = 'flip'; 
    this.slides.paginationType = 'fraction'; 
    this.slides.pager = false; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use effect property like this `effect="flip"`

```
<ion-slides pager #mainslider effect="flip">
    <ion-slide style="background-color: aquamarine">
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide style="background-color:lightblue;">
      <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide style="background-color:darkcyan;">
      <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Comment: Thanks @chatar singh